# How to calculate size of table in DB2

Tags: db2-400

I am working on db2 database first time.
My requirement is to get the size of each table in MB/GB in a given schema.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried examples from IBM documentation such as [these](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0052897.html)? If you get stuck in your attempts, add your problems to your question.

Comment: @blackpen From the link above tried SELECT * FROM SYSIBMADM.ADMINTABINFO but got ADMINTABINFO in SYSIBMADM type *FILE not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the many solutions:

```
select tabschema || '.' || tabname "table",
  decimal((data_object_p_size + index_object_p_size +
        long_object_p_size + lob_object_p_size +
        xml_object_p_size)/1024,10,2) "physical_space_mb",
   decimal((data_object_l_size + index_object_l_size +
        long_object_l_size + lob_object_l_size +
        xml_object_l_size)/1024,10,2) "logical_space_mb"
from sysibmadm.admintabinfo
where tabschema not like 'SYS%'
order by 2 desc;
```

Answer (score 7):

on db2 iseries you can do it

```
 SELECT NUMBER_ROWS, DATA_SIZE FROM qsys2.systablestat 
 WHERE 
 TABLE_SCHEMA ='YOURLIBNAME' and table_name='YOURTABLENAME'
```